# AngularJS http POST take lot of time to load data

Tags: angularjs, http

i have a problem in loading data take from 1 to 30 seconds to load 10000 GPS coordinates ,
after checking the server side i see server take 300ms of traitement between database query  and do some traitement and send response to AngularJS side

```
var getItineraryVehicule_n=function (id_v,date_s,date_e) {
return $q(function (resolve,reject) {
  var LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY = 'yourTokenKey';
  var token= window.localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY);
  token=JSON.parse(token.split('#')[0]);
  $httpBackend.whenPOST(/.*/).passThrough();
  $http({
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: SERVER.url+token.response.response.user.id+'/itinerary_mongodb',
    header: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },

    data: {
      "date_s": date_s ,
      "date_e": date_e,

      "id_v":id_v

    }
  }).success(function (result) {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    resolve(result);
  }).error(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    reject('error itinerary vehicule');
  });
});
```

}

Comment: What is the time it took in the network tab in the developer tools in your browser?
Because maybe the issue in the UI rendering

Comment: network tab take 1.27s but a have added an console.log after response to caculate the time between send of POST API and loading data it give me 3.7s the size of data is 223Kb

Comment: Can you please include the code that logs the time so we can see what is going on

Comment: i think the problem is in the size of data what i want to load 
this line is one of the list of data that i want to load 
{"datetime":1596785496000,"engine":1,"latitude":34.8310483,"deviation":33,"counter":0.073,"speed":6,"longitude":-5.9006116}
i want to load the itinerarys of one day 10000 line like that just to draw itinerary in the map the size final of response data is from 400Kb to 1Mb i don't know if that can infect the time of response and what i need to do in this case , 
thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

i have just doing that but after several times of testing I see that time in the network tab is the same in the console.log time

```
 var getItineraryVehicule_n=function (id_v,date_s,date_e) {
var d = new Date();
return $q(function (resolve,reject) {
  var LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY = 'yourTokenKey';
  var token= window.localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY);
  token=JSON.parse(token.split('#')[0]);
  $httpBackend.whenPOST(/.*/).passThrough();
  $http({
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: SERVER.url+token.response.response.user.id+'/itinerary_mongodb',
    header: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },

    data: {
      "date_s": date_s ,
      "date_e": date_e,

      "id_v":id_v

    }
  }).success(function (result) {
    console.log("in the service is take : "+(new Date().getTime()-d.getTime()));
    resolve(result);
  }).error(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    reject('error itinerary vehicule');
  });
});
```

}